# Swift: property that is a UIView subclass implementing a protocol

Tags: class, swift, properties, polymorphism, protocols

Here's the scenario. I have a number of different views I want to show, depending on the model object I'm showing the user. So I've set up a protocol whereby any view that implements it can be presented.

```
class MyItem { /* some model properties */ }

protocol ItemView: class {
    // some protocol methods (e.g. updateWithItem(), etc)
    func setupItem(item: MyItem)
}

class SpecificItemView: UIView, ItemView { /* there will be multiple classes like this */
    func setupItem(item: MyItem) {
        // do item setup
    }
}

class AnotherItemView: UIView, ItemView {
    func setupItem(item: MyItem) {
        // do DIFFERENT item setup
    }
}
```

Then when I go to use them in a view controller, I've been given one of my ItemView classes:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    var itemView: ItemView? // could be a SpecificItemView or AnotherItemView

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        itemView?.setupItem(MyItem())
        itemView?.removeFromSuperview() /* this line won't compile */
    }
}
```

Everything works except that last line, where I try to call up to a `UIView` method (`removeFromSuperview`). No surprise there, since `ItemView` has no relation to `UIView`.

In Objective C I would solve this issue by specifying my itemView ivar like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView<ItemView> *itemView;
```

But I can't seem to find a similar syntax for Swift. I suspect there is no way to use this pattern in Swift. How do I achieve my overall goal of interchangeable UIView classes in a Swift-friendly manner?

One *hacky* solution I've found so far, is to add any `UIView` methods I call (e.g. `removeFromSuperview`) to my `ItemView` protocol.

Another suggestion I got, not on SO, from [Maurice Kelly](http://blog.chatswood.org.uk), was to  make a `UIView` subclass, implementing the `ItemView` protocol, that both `SpecificItemView` and `AnotherItemView` can descend from. You can see it [implemented in this gist](https://gist.github.com/coryalder/b5405b9abac79013c791). While that solves the issue of encapsulating class AND protocol in a single type (e.g. `var itemView: ItemViewParentClass`) it basically makes the protocol pointless, since you're now implementing all the protocol's methods in your parent class and overriding them in your subclasses. The single biggest drawback of this solutions is that you have to cast instances of subclasses (`SpecificItemView`) to the new hypthetical parent class (`ItemViewParentClass`) when you refer to them in your View Controller.

Comment: Whats the error message from the compiler?

Comment: Your itemview does not extend UIView

Comment: Your sample code would need to change to `var itemView:SpecificItemView?`

Comment: @Aggressor clarified my question a bit. Need to support multiple subclasses.

Answer (score 5):

As of Swift 5, this is possible by constraining your protocol to only be applied to `UIViews`. To do this, just do the following:

```
protocol ItemView: UIView {
  func setupItem(item: MyItem)
}
```

By adding this constraint to your protocol, any object that the swift compiler recognizes as an `ItemView` will also have all `UIView` methods available on it.

Similarly, if a non-`UIView` subclass attempts to implement the `ItemView` protocol, your code will not compile.

Answer (score 1):

As you're discovering, there's no way to specify both a class and a protocol for an object.

The easiest way to fix the problem is to add `removeFromSuperview` (and any other `UIView` methods you need to insure are present) to your protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following (in Swift 4) would do the trick?

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    typealias T = UIView & ItemView

    var itemView: T?
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`ItemView` does not extend `UIView`, but your `SpecificItemView` does. Naturally, no `removeFromSuperView` exists on your `ItemView`.

In your ViewController you declare an `ItemView` type object, rather than a `SpecificItemView`

Change your `MyViewController` code to:

```
var itemView:SpecificItemView?
```

Comment: That would work, except that the goal here is to have a couple of different `SpecificItemView` classes, e.g. `SongItemView` and `AlbumItemView`

Comment: Can you tell me why ItemView does not extend UIView in the first place?

Comment: I dont see a good reason (but maybe there is!) currently, but assuming there is, could you not just create your own remove() function, and whenenever you instantiate a subclass, you assign that member variable and call remove on that? So your ItemView has a generic View member variable that gets assigned when you call setupItem?